# Facebook like button counting problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, sharing, facebook-fbml, facebook-sharer

I have installed facebook like button with javascript solution.

I left the href attribute empty so it will use the current url for counting. It seems that right now , even after changing the href attribute , facebook is counting the like on my entire website.

Example: 
1. domain.com/fb_url
2. domain.com/fb_url2

If you will like the first url , you will be able to see the likes on the second url.

Answer (score 1):

Why not putting into the href attribute the absolute URL of the page? I guess this will fix the issue. This can be easily achieved in whatever language you use. Please post the code you are using so that we can provide further help.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `og:url` tag, you although have to change it on each page.